# if $f$ is entire function, $f(0)=1$, find $f(1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

if $f$ is entire function, $f(0)=1$ and satisfy that $|f(z)-e^z\cdot\sin 2z|<4$ for all $z$ in $C$. find the value of $f(1)$.

I have tried to input $z=0$ or $z=1$ but I only get inequality for $f(1)$.

Comment: inequality for $f(1)$?. Demonstrate what you mean. You may get an inequality for its modulus, but certainly you can't compare two complex numbers.

Comment: What is $\sin z$ doing inside?

Comment: Here's a hint. The difference of the two functions you have is a bounded entire function. What does that tell you?

Comment: yes, inequality for its modulus. $|f(1)-e.sin 2|<4$

Comment: so this mean that the function is constant ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Liouville's theorem tells you that every bounded entire function is constant. Hence $f(z)-e^z\cdot \sin 2z$ is constant.

Comment: i get $f(z)=e^z.sin2z+1$. is that true ?

Comment: @jamesbrown Yes that is correct.